# Naming or Tagging UITextViews in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need to specify one `textView` in which I want to update the text. I have tried the following:

```
func updateView(message: String) {
    var textView2 = UITextView.viewWithTag(2)
    textView2.text = message
}
```

but I receive this error:

`type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertable`

Comment: `viewWithTag` must be sent to the superview. It's an instance method, not a class method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You are trying to get textview's subview, which is not correct. Instead, you should query superview for `UITextView`.  It should be:

```
func updateView(message: String) {
    var textView2 = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as UITextView;
    textView2.text = message
}
```

Comment: I doesn't know about this. +1 Good Answer

Answer (score 3):

**In swift, you have to  typecast and moreover you have to provide the superview**

```
 var textView2 : UITextView? = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextView;
```

*So your function should be like this:-*

```
func updateView(message: String) {
    var textView2 : UITextView? = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextView;
    textView2.text = message
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If viewWithTag() is used to "find" a component from a Storyboard, it's good to know about IBOutlets:

http://codewithchris.com/9-hooking-it-all-up-swift-iboutlet-properties/

Around 2:30